# CreateProcess can start a process, but QProcess cannot... why?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, qt4

I am writing a windows QT app that needs to launch other apps. If I use the following windows calls everything works fine:

```
QString qsExePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Some Company\\SomeApp.exe";
QString qsCommandLine = "";


DWORD dwLastError = 0;
STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));
startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
startupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
startupInfo.wShowWindow = (WORD)1;

PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
ZeroMemory(&processInfo, sizeof(processInfo));

if (CreateProcess((TCHAR*)(qsExePath.utf16()), (TCHAR*)(qsCommandLine.utf16()), 
    NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, 
    &startupInfo, &processInfo))
{
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
}
else
{
    dwLastError = GetLastError();
}
```

However, if I use the following QT calls it does not work and fails with QProcess::Unknown Error.

```
QProcess process;
bool bStarted = process.startDetached(qsExePath);
qDebug()  << process.error();
```

I can get QProcess to work if copy SomeApp.exe to my %TMP% directory and change the qsExePath accordingly, so it is obviously some kind of permissions error. I don't understand why though... if it were really permissions, shouldn't my CreateProcess windows call fail?

Comment: Don't type-cast the result of `QString.utf16()` to a `TCHAR*`. If the code is compiled in an ANSI configuration, `TCHAR` will map to `char` instead of `wchar_t` and `CreateProcess()` will map to `CreateProcessA()`, thus you will be passing bad data to it.  Remove the type-cast and call `CreateProcessW()` directly instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your path has spaces in it.  You are calling the overloaded version of `QProcess.startDetached()` that takes a single parameter, so it interprets that as the complete command line to execute.  As such, try wrapping the path in quotes, otherwise it will think that "C:\Program" is the program to execute and everything else are arguments, which would be wrong:

```
QString qsExePath = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Some Company\\SomeApp.exe\"";
bool bStarted = process.startDetached(qsExePath);
```

Alternatively, call one of the other overloaded versions of `startDetached()` and let it work out the necessary quoting internally for you:

```
QString qsExePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Some Company\\SomeApp.exe";
bool bStarted = process.startDetached(qsExePath, QStringList());
```

Comment: I strongly recommend the second version. Less hassle, less error prone, works on all platforms.